# Cascading dropdowns with AngularJs with Select Distinct

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a page on which I output a list of Cars. The results in this list are coming from a Json file.

This is an example of my Json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1590",
    "brand": "Peugeot",
    "type": "508"
  },
  {
    "id": "1591",
    "brand": "Peugeot",
    "type": "308"
  },
  {
    "id": "1594",
    "brand": "Honda",
    "type": "Civic"
  },
  {
    "id": "1605",
    "brand": "Renault",
    "type": "Clio"
  },
  {
    "id": "1607",
    "brand": "Renault",
    "type": "Laguna"
  }
]
```

I need to filter the results by e.g. Brand and Type. So I have two DropDown lists named 'selectedBrand' and 'selectedType'.

I used this markup to load the single Brands into the DropDown list:

```
<select id="brands" data-ng-model="selectedBrand" data-ng-options="car.brand for car in cars | unique:'brand' | orderBy:'brand'">
</select>
```

This works okay and gives me a DropDown list with the unique brands, like a DISTINCT SELECT.

Now I want the second DropDown list to be filtered when the first one has a selected value.
This is the markup I have for the second DropDown list:

```
<select id="type" data-ng-model="selectedType" data-ng-options="car.type for car in cars | filter:{brand:selectedBrand} | unique:'type' | orderBy:'type'">
</select>
```

But this is not working. It shows the complete list with types of every brand.

I guess I need some way to trigger it when the first DropDown list changes?
I pretty new to AngularJs, so any help would be appreciated.

I don't know if this is the best way to get those DISTINCT values out of the Json results. I only have this complete Json result set with all the data and that is what I have to work with.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Yes, sure. This is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7p7tM/6/

Answer (score 1):

Following [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) you'll need a `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'your option here' }"` to do this bind